# PySpark WARN messages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can I disable the following WARN messages when running PySpark code:

```
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
18/06/08 21:04:55 WARN SparkConf: In Spark 1.0 and later spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).
18/06/08 21:04:55 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
```

I spent some time playing with log4.properties, but cannot figure out exactly which class logs these.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your init of the spark context:

```
sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
```

Comment: This suppresses the message, but presumably the OP wants to address the warning problem?